# Why am I getting a file 2 times when fetching a php via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, output-buffering

It's quite curious to me. I've got a php test file like this:

```
<div class="live-ajax-messages">message from deep ajax</div>
```

I'll get it using this function:

```
public function get_ajax_messages_template() {
    ob_start();
    include(__DIR__. '/../templates/search-results-messages.php');
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    exit($content);
}
```

I'll get that function output like this:

```
    load_ajax_messages_template: function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            data: 'action=my_action', // executes get_ajax_messages_template
            dataType: 'html',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response); // getting 2 times <div class="live-ajax-messages">message from deep ajax</div>
                //this.results_el.find('.ajax-results').html(response);
            }.bind(this),
        })
    },
```

Basically, I'll get

```
<div class="live-ajax-messages">message from deep ajax</div>
<div class="live-ajax-messages">message from deep ajax</div>
```

Why?

Comment: Can you share more details? What's the problem you are facing? What have you tried to resolve it? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output buffering (the `ob_*` functions) temporarily buffer output. If the script exits while there is still buffered output, it will be written to the response.

So, here you are buffering the output of `search-results-messages.php`. The call to `ob_get_contents` returns the current buffer, but does not clear it.

Then, when you call `exit($contents)` it is writing the contents to the response, then flushing the output buffer which *also* contains the contents.

There are two possible solutions here. (1) is to replace `ob_get_contents` with `ob_get_clean` which does the same thing, but clears the buffer.

The other (simpler) solution is to just include the file *without* output buffering, since you want to write its contents out anyway, then just call `exit();` with no parameters.